# Изменение цвета у NSTableHeaderView

Tags: objective-c, tableview

Есть какие-нибудь методы кастомизировать хедер у **view-based** NSTableView? Или как-нибудь поменять цвет заголовка у таблицы? Очень мало информации по этому вопросу нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел пока только такой метод, но рисует поверх текста, поэтому приходится уменьшать альфа. Может быть кто-нибудь знает менее кривой метод?

```
    NSGradient *gradientToFill = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.f green:0.f blue:0.35f alpha:0.1]
                                                           endingColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.5546875 green:0.59765625 blue:0.66015625 alpha:0.1]];
[gradientToFill drawInRect:dirtyRect angle:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Создать собственный subclass от NSTableHeaderView.
Задать таблице необходимый header через свойство

```
@property(strong) NSTableHeaderView *headerView
```

Comment: Речь идет о NSTableView, это не тоже самое что UITableView.

Comment: Поправил для mac

Answer (score 0):

Код меняющий колонку шапки в NSTableView:

```
NSString *title = @"Your Title";
NSTableColumn *yourColumn = self.tableView.tableColumns.lastObject;
    [yourColumn.headerCell setStringValue:title];
```

Comment: Речь идет о NSTableView, это не тоже самое что UITableView.